# multiple line tag content replacement if content matches

Tags: perl, replace, tags, sed, awk

I am not very proficient in perl, awk, or sed and I have been searching the web for a solution to my problem for some while now, but wasn't very successful.

I would like to replace

`<math> ... </math>`

with

`<math>\begin{align} ... \end{align}</math>`

**if** `...` contains `\\`. My problem is that the string between the `<math>` tags can span multiple lines. I managed to replace the tags within one line with sed but couldn't get it to run for multiple lines.

Any simple solution with perl, awk, or sed is very welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate expressions for each tag and the script will be immune to multilinedness:

```
sed -e 's,<math>,&\\begin{align},g' -e 's,</math>,&\\end{align},g'
```

Edit:
Multiline awk version:

```
awk '/<math>/,/<\/math>/ {
  if (index($0, "<math>")) { 
    a=$0
  } else {
    b = b $0
  }
  if (index($0, "</math>")) {
    if (index(b,"\\\\")) {
      sub("<math>","&\\begin{align}", a)
      sub("</math>","\\end{align}&", b)
    }; 
    print a,b
    a=""
    b=""
  } 
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but I only want to replace the stuff between the tags if it contains a \\. I wasn't able to accomplish that.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that part. For multiple lines, awk will do better.

Comment: If you can give any example how to accomplish that I would be grateful. Otherwise thanks for the hint.

Comment: there you go. Vary the amount of \\ as needed.

Comment: Cool, that almost does it. How do I need to modify it if the amount of \\ can be arbitrary (but at least 1). Thanks again.

Comment: in which case doesn't it work? It should already match more than one occurence, since it only looks at the first.

Comment: when <math> \\ </math> is in a single line.

Comment: oh, I didn't even try to handle that, since you said you have it covered. You can run both separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try next `perl` command. How it works? It reads content file in slurp mode saving it in `$f` variable and later add with a regexp in single mode (match newlines with `.`) `\begin{regex}` and `\end{regex}` if found `\\` between *math* tags.

```
perl -e '
    do { 
        $/ = undef; 
        $f = <> 
    }; 
    $f =~ s#(<math>)(.*\\\\.*)(</math>)#$1\\begin{align}$2\\end{align}$3#s; 
    printf qq|%s|, $f
' infile
```

Comment: Hi Birei, thanks for your help. Your script did not produce the desired results so I am sticking with lynxlynxlynx awk script.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba}
/[\x00\x01\x02]/q1
s/<math>/\x00/g
s/<\/math>/\x01/g
s/\\\\/\x02/g
s/\x00\([^\x01\x02]*\)\x01/<math>\1<\/math>/g
s/\x00/<math>\\begin{align}/g
s/\x01/\\end{align}<\/math>/g
s/\x02/\\\\/g' file
```